# How to set up a user community in wordpress with basic profile pages?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, profile

I am trying to make a website with wordpress such that users can register/login,
and when they login, they have only access to change a few fields about them.
Then I want to list these user profiles in the main site.

I searched a little and came across buddypress, but anyone has easier/other suggestions?
Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "[Extra User Detail](http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-user-details/)" plugin to add the fields you want at user profile. Then you can use "[Author Avatars list](http://wordpress.org/plugins/author-avatars/)" or "[EP Display Users](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ep-display-users/)" or "[Members List Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members-list/)" to show them on your site.